# Dual boot (Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10) on Motherboard MSI Gaming M5 Z270

Tags: dual-boot, msi

I'm trying to install dual boot on my pc, but i can't because when i load the installation, my screen stays black and i can't do anything in there excepet shutdown or reboot the pc to Windows 10. I already cleared CMOS manually, load optimized values default, disable fast boot, enable/disable secure boot and reinstalled Windows 10 and everything i done was useless. Any ideas how to solve this problem ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks, but didin't help solved the problem

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Everything in that link...I could solve half of the problem, but now i can't install grub, because the system don't recognize windows loader and when i try to install in a partition i created, appears the message "EFI partition not found, the installation process will not be succeeded". I already tried to do it manually, but after install the linux, grub don't load and windows don't work correctly, even if i select in BIOS the disk with windows.